# jQuery Tooltip on .click instead of hover for chrome extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-chrome

Wanted to reach out and ask to see if anybody has had any experience designing Chrome extensions. I saw my buddy in a slack chat talking about how great it would be if there was a plugin that prevented mailto: links from going straight to your mail app, and instead let you choose to either copy the email in the link or proceed with the mailto: functionality.

So far, I went ahead and found a way to target ONLY the mailto: links on the page, prevented their default action, and then I got stuck. I'm wondering if there's a way to initiate the tooltip on a click function rather than a hover, and to dynamically insert an element into the mailto: function to open a tooltip window with the two user actions I was describing above.

Anybody have any ideas? I'm totally out of them, not really sure how to proceed :(

https://codepen.io/matthewvolk/pen/brOEgz

```js
// Select ONLY mailto elements on DOM
$('a[href^="mailto:"]').click(function (event) {

    // Prevent default mailto: action
    event.preventDefault();

    // Open tooltip containing mailto/copy option
    $('a[href^="mailto:"]').tooltip({

        // This is where I'm stuck

    });

});
```

```html
<a href="mailto:someone@example.com?Subject=Hello%20again" target="_top" title="test">MailTo Action</a> 
<br /><br />
<a href="https://google.com/" target="_blank">Link that still works</a>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well one thing you could do is loop through each mailto link when the page loads and add your tooltip to it before hand, but have those hidden by default in your CSS.

Then, on click, toggle the visibility of the tooltip.

Here's an example where the tooltip only contains the mailto link, but you can of course add additional markup in the `.each()` function that you want to include in the tooltip.

In the tooltip creation process, we use `$(this).attr('href')` and `$(this).text()` to fill out the link inside the tooltip. (`$(this)` referring to each link with an href that starts with "mailto:".)

Then we wrap our original link and the tooltip we just created in a wrapper, which allows us to easily position the tooltip in our stylesheet.

```js
$(function(){
  var mailtoLinks = $('a[href^="mailto:"]').each(function(){
    $(this).before(
      '<div class="tooltip">' +
      '<a href="' + $(this).attr('href') + '">' +
      $(this).text() + '</a>' +
      '</div>'
    );
    $(this).add($(this).prev('.tooltip')).wrapAll('<div class="tooltip-wrapper"></div>');
  });
  
  // Select ONLY mailto elements on DOM
  $(mailtoLinks).click(function(event) {
    // Prevent default mailto: action
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).prev('.tooltip').toggle();
  });
});
```

```css
.tooltip-wrapper {
  position: relative;
}
.tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: calc(-100% - 15px);
  left: -5px;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: lightgray;
  display: none;
}
.tooltip::after {
  content: '';
  border-top: 10px solid lightgray;
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -10px;
  left: calc(50% - 7.5px);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div style="margin-left: 15%; margin-top: 15%">
<a href="mailto:someone@example.com?Subject=Hello%20again" target="_top">MailTo Action</a> 

<br />
<br />
<br />

<a href="https://google.com/" target="_blank">Link that still works</a>
</div>
```

Note that the Google "link that still works" doesn't seem to work in this snippet, but I think that's a Stack Overflow behavior and not related to this code.

Comment: This is so awesome! I definitely would not have thought to take this approach. Maybe I need to keep learning ;) I'm still a beginner lol.

Quick question, wondering if there's a way to manipulate the text within the tooltip to be different?

And if there's a ways to use jQuery to copy text in the html element? I'm gonna start googling around. THANK YOU SO MUCH for the help!!!!

Comment: @matthewvolk Happy to help. And yes, of course you can change the text in the tooltip. In the script. you see that we are creating an `<a>` tag and then we insert `$(this).text()` before the closing `</a>` tag. But you can put whatever else besides `$(this).text()` in there that you want. You can get the text of any element on the page with the `.text()` method. You just do `$(.some-selector).text()`. If you want the same text for all tooltips, it'd be better to cache that in a variable and then use that variable inside the `.each()` function. api.jquery.com has everything you need to know!

Comment: You are the BEST. Like I said, I'm still learning, and to get this kind of advice is incredibly helpful. Thanks so much cjl!!!!!!!

Comment: @matthewvolk No problem man. Just takes some practice to figure this stuff out. Best of luck to you. And friendly reminder since you're new here: you can leave your question open as long as you want to see if other answers come along, but at some point you should accept an answer if it addresses all your questions (whether that's this one or another). And you can upvote any answers that you find helpful, whether you accept them or not.

Comment: Awesome! Just clicked the green check mark, hopefully that does it!